# How can I create breadcrumbs using pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am looking for a way to create breadcrumbs with pyqt. So I have a main panel which loads few attributes. the header and footer remains the same for all the panels.So now in the first panel when I click on a button it takes me to the second panel. So I am looking for something like Panel1->Panel2 which is to be shown in the bottom and when I click on Panel1 it should take me to panel1.Could you let me know how I can achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [qbreadcrumb](https://github.com/juancarlospaco/qbreadcrumb) widget for this. Though it is not well documented, you can download and customize it according to your needs.

Comment: This is a link-only answer which shows exactly why link-only answers are bad: the link is dead.

Comment: Ha ha ha, true, this was answered 5 years ago.I should share the snippet instead of sharing the link.